# Importing values in Python

Tags: python, class, import, tkinter

I have a little module that creates a window (program1). I've imported this into another python program of mine (program2).

How do I make program 2 get self.x and x that's in program1?

This is program1.

```
import Tkinter

class Class(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.Main()

    def Main(self):
        self.button= Tkinter.Button(self,text='hello')
        self.button.pack()

        self.x = 34
        x = 62





def run():
    app = Class(None)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the variable `self.x` as a member of an instance of `Class`:

```
c = Class(parent)
print(c.x)
```

You cannot access the local variable - it goes out of scope when the method call ends.

Comment: With c = Class(parent)
print(c.x) I keep getting the error that parent isn't defined.

Comment: Why should parent be defined there? I think you should start at more basic python and OO projects.

Comment: `c = Class(parent)` is equivalent to the line `app = Class(None)` in your program1. So, setting parent to None should work.

Comment: @Anteater7171: I suggest you should start from some beginner tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207701/python-tutorial-for-total-beginners

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what the purpose of 'self.x' and 'x' are but one thing to note in the 'Main' method of class Class

```
def Main(self):
        self.button= Tkinter.Button(self,text='hello')
        self.button.pack()

        self.x = 34
        x = 62
```

is that 'x' and 'self.x' are two different variables. The variable 'x' is a local variable for the method 'Main' and 'self.x' is an instance variable. Like Mark says you can access the instance variable 'self.x' as an attribute of an instance of Class, but the method variable 'x' is only accessible from within the 'Main' method. If you would like to have the ability to access the method variable 'x' then you could change the signature of the 'Main' method as follows.

```
def Main(self,x=62):
    self.button= Tkinter.Button(self,text='hello')
    self.button.pack()

    self.x = 34
    return x
```

This way you can set the value of the method variable 'x' when you call the 'Main' method from an instance of Class

```
>> c = Class()
>> c.Main(4)
4
```

or just keep the default

```
>> c.Main()
62
```

and as before like Mark said you will have access to the instance variable 'self.x'

```
>> c.x
34
```